# invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'create_property'

Tags: python, django

I'm getting this error while using one of my django views. I have 2 models; Owner and Property. An owner can have many properties. The models are as below:

```
class Owner(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    trading_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.trading_name


class Property(models.Model):

    STYLE_CHOICES = [('Apart','Apartment'),
                        ('Bung','Bungalow'),
                        ('Mans','Mansionnete'),
                        ('Comm','Commercial'),
                    ]
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(Owner, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    style = models.CharField(max_length=100, choices=STYLE_CHOICES)
    bedrooms = models.IntegerField()
    bathrooms = models.IntegerField()
    parking = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    sqft = models.IntegerField()
    address = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='photos/%Y/%m/%d', blank=True)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

My views are:

```
def CreatePropertyView(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = PropertyForm(request.POST)
        print(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            property = form.save(commit=False)
            property.save()
            return redirect(reverse('properties'))
    return render(request, 'property_agency/property_form.html', {'form': PropertyForm(request.POST or None)})



def PropertyListView(request):
    properties = Property.objects.all()
    context = {
            'properties': properties
    }
    return render(request, 'property_agency/property_list.html', context=context)



def PropertyDetailView(request, property_id, *args, **kwargs):
    property = Property.objects.get(pk=property_id)
    units = PropertyUnit.objects.filter(property=property)
    context = {
        'property': property,
        'units': units
    }
    return render(request, 'property_agency/property_detail.html', context=context)
```

The PropertyListView with url 'properties' is working just fine. Also PropertyDetailView is working fine, however when i go to 'properties/create_property' it blows out. The stack trace highlights the line:

```
property = Property.objects.get(pk=property_id)
```

of my PropertyDetailView as the line with an issue. It started after messing with migrations. I have tried deleting the database and removing migrations but still. Any ideas how to fix this, thanks.

My url config:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('pages.urls')),
    path('listings/', include('listings.urls')),
    path('accounts/', include('accounts.urls')),
    path('contacts/', include('contacts.urls')),
    path('owners/', agency_views.OwnersListView, name='owners'),
    path('owners/create_owner/', CreateOwnerView.as_view(), name='create_owner'),
    path('owners/<owner_id>/', agency_views.OwnerDetailView, name='owner_detail'),
    path('properties/', agency_views.PropertyListView, name='properties'),
    path('properties/<property_id>/', agency_views.PropertyDetailView, name='property_detail'),
    path('properties/create_property/', agency_views.CreatePropertyView, name='create_property'),
    path('properties/create_unit/', agency_views.CreateUnitView, name='create_unit'),
    path('tenants/', TenantListView.as_view(), name='tenants'),
    path('tenants/create_tenant/', CreateTenantView.as_view(), name='create_tenant'),
    path('realtors/', RealtorsListView.as_view(), name='realtors'),
    path('realtors/create_realtor/', RealtorCreateView.as_view(), name='create_realtor'),
]
```

and in my html template:

```
<button type=""><a href="{% url 'create_property' %}">Create New Property</a></button>

<td><a href="{% url 'property_detail' property.id %}"><span class="badge badge-primary badge-pill">View</span></a></td>
```

Stacktrace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/muhurijson/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/home/muhurijson/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/home/muhurijson/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/home/muhurijson/Desktop/mySuite/projects/grant_ventures/property_agency/views.py", line 57, in PropertyDetailView
    property = Property.objects.get(pk=property_id)
  File "/home/muhurijson/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 82, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/muhurijson/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 399, in get
    clone = self.filter(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/muhurijson/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 892, in filter
    return self._filter_or_exclude(False, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/muhurijson/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 910, in _filter_or_exclude
    clone.query.add_q(Q(*args, **kwargs))
  File "/home/muhurijson/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1290, in add_q
    clause, _ = self._add_q(q_object, self.used_aliases)
  File "/home/muhurijson/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1315, in _add_q
    child_clause, needed_inner = self.build_filter(
  File "/home/muhurijson/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1251, in build_filter
    condition = self.build_lookup(lookups, col, value)
  File "/home/muhurijson/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1116, in build_lookup
    lookup = lookup_class(lhs, rhs)
  File "/home/muhurijson/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/lookups.py", line 20, in __init__
    self.rhs = self.get_prep_lookup()
  File "/home/muhurijson/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/lookups.py", line 70, in get_prep_lookup
    return self.lhs.output_field.get_prep_value(self.rhs)
  File "/home/muhurijson/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 966, in get_prep_value
    return int(value)
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'create_property'
```

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
path('properties/<int:property_id>/', agency_views.PropertyDetailView, name='property_detail'),
```

So that paths that look like `properties/abc/` don't get routed to your `PropertyDetailView`.

In general, you should always list the paths with angle brackets after similar paths without angle brackets, because Django picks the first matching routing rule.

Comment: That's good to hear. Please accept my answer by pressing the check mark under the upvote/downvote buttons to signal to the site and the community that your question was answered!

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you make a call to URL ... properties/create_property/ and it gets caught by the line above and 'create_property' is used as <property_id>

I think you should declare it as int:

```
 ../<int:property_id>/
```

```
path('properties/<property_id>/', agency_views.PropertyDetailView, name='property_detail'),
    path('properties/create_property/', agency_views.CreatePropertyView, name='create_property'),
```